# Find the distribution of $X$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

> > $U \sim \mathrm {Unif} (0,1)$. Let $\alpha > 0$. Then find the density function of $X=U^{-\frac 1 {\alpha}}$. I have found that if $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of the random variable $X$ then 
> >     $$
> > F(x) = \left\{
> >         \begin{array}{ll}
> >             0 & \quad \frac {1} {x^{\alpha}} < 0 \\
> >             1 - x^{-\alpha} & \quad 0 < \frac 1 {x^{\alpha}} < 1 \\
> >             1 & \quad \frac {1} {x^{\alpha}} > 1
> >         \end{array}
> >     \right.
> > $$

Can it be simplified more? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: But the problem is that $F$ is not defined at $0$.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 CDF are right-continuous.

Comment: @drhab The random variable is greater than $1$ so the expressions obtained by OP are wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is this: $F(x)=0$ for $x<1$ and $F(x)=1-x^{-\alpha}$ for $x \geq 1$. The density is given by $f(x)=0$ for $x<1$ and $f(x)=\alpha x^{-\alpha -1}$ for $x >1$

Comment: sir that means $X \sim \mathrm {Pareto}\ ({\alpha})$. Right?

Comment: You could equally say $F(x)=0$ for $x\le 1$ and $F(x)=1-x^{-\alpha}$ for $x \gt 1$

Comment: @Henry Of course! I don't know what point you are trying to make because your answer and mine are exactly the same.